# Python - Qt. How to make a Terminal Window for Telnet or ssh server interaction

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt4, qt-designer

i am making a PyQt application, and i want to make something like a Terminal Window, where the user can interact with a Telnet or ssh server.

My first idea was to have a Window with a black QPlainTextEdit and a scrollbar.

I am new to python-Qt world and would appreciate some guidance. Any ideas?

Thanks :-)

Answer (score 6):

Here's a link to a terminal program written in C++ using Qt. I'm not sure how helpful it will be for the low level stuff but I'm sure the Qt parts will be helpful. http://sourceforge.net/projects/qtermwidget/

Comment: Thank you Arnold :-) This looks interesting, i will start reading the code to see how its done.